# How can I use a disposable 35mm camera's lens on my regular cameras?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, disposable-cameras

I want to use the lens from a disposable 35mm film camera on my regular cameras (Nikon F mount, Sony E Mount, etc). I've been Googling and searching and have not been able to find any material that describes how to do it. I'm not really sure what would be involved in extracting the lens from a disposable camera and adapting it to a regular cameras mount. I'm also willing to just buy a pre-made one but I haven't been able to find that either. Any ideas?

Comment: I have cameras with Sony E Mount and Nikon F mount that I would like to use it on

Comment: *In my opinion*, the quality of a disposable camera lens ( which camera ? ) is not worth the time, effort and expense to do this. **Why do you want to do this ?**

Comment: because I like the image quality of disposable cameras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use the lens from a disposable 35mm film camera on my regular cameras (Nikon F mount, Sony E Mount, etc).

Adapting the lens from a single-use camera has a low probability of success.

- Portions of the lens housing may be molded into the camera housing. It may not hold the elements together when cut away from the rest of the camera.
- The [registration distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) of single-use camera lenses is less than the thickness of the camera, ~25mm.

  - This is far too short to use on DSLR cameras. It *might* work with some mirrorless cameras, but there won't be much room to work with.
  - The lens *may* work when attached to a lens cap with a hole drilled into it, but it depends on the FFD of your camera.
  - To adapt arbitrary lenses, I use a short M42/C-mount adapter and M42-M42 helicoid. The helicoid and adapter aren't able to bring single-use camera lenses close enough to the sensor to focus at infinity. Depending on your objectives, other lenses may be adapted.

> I'm also willing to just buy a pre-made one...

Some manufacturers make lo-fi lenses.

- Diana F+ 38mm Lens ~$40 + Diana F+ Lens adapter (EF) ~$20
- Holga 60mm f/8 Lens (NF, EF) ~$20
- [Lomo Art Lenses](https://shop.lomography.com/en/lenses/art-lenses)

  - Lomo LC-A Minitar-1 Art 32mm f/2.8 (L39, Leica M-mount) ~$350
  - Lomogon 32mm f/2.5 Art (NF, EF, PK) ~$600
- Loreo [Lens in a Cap](http://www.loreo.com/pages/products/loreo_lenscap.html) 35mm f/5.6 (PK, EF, FD, NF, MD, M42, Minolta AF) ~$27
- Olympus M.Zuiko 9mm f/8 Fisheye Body Cap Lens (MFT) ~$100
- Olympus M.Zuiko 15mm f/8 Body Cap Lens (MFT) ~$50
- Pinhole body caps on your favorite auction site.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the Holga 60mm f/8 for Nikon F locally for only $20. Also was able to get an adapter for my Sony and it seems to fit. Looks like this might be a good solution for this kind of image, I am trying it out.

Comment: Problem with the Holga lens might be its focal length.  A lot of fixed-focus cameras have ~38mm lenses (~25mm on APS-C).